# Optimizing a method that generates more than 1000 objects of the same type

Tags: performance, c

This simple piece of software is generating a vehicle object by using the get_vehicle() function,

Whenever i need to generate a specific vehicle I pass in the vehicle ID to this method and it returns the appropriate vehicle.

Within the get_vehicle() function, each vehicle is generated within a case label within a switch statement,

This code isn't very efficient because i need to generate 1000 vehicles i'll have to feed each vehicle information in its own case label, which can cause a maintenance nightmare,

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    typedef struct Vehicle 
    {
      char type[10]; //Suv, sedan, hatchback
      char make[10]; //toyota , nissan, ford
      char model[10]; //toyota-LANDCRUISER, nissan_maxima, ford_ranger
      int manufacturing_year;



    }Vehicle;

    Vehicle get_vehicle(int vehicle_ID);

    int main()
    {


        Vehicle toyota_landcruizer = get_vehicle(1);
        Vehicle nissan_maxima = get_vehicle(2);
        Vehicle ford_ranger = get_vehicle(3);
        printf("Make 1 is %s \n",toyota_landcruizer.make);
        printf("Make 2 is %s \n",nissan_maxima.make);
        printf("Make 3 is %s \n",ford_ranger.make);

        return 0;
    }

    void copyString(char new_string[], char dest_string[])
    {
        //we are assuming string length will always be less than 10
        int i,length;
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            dest_string[i] = '\0'; //initialize the destination string with proper state

        length = strlen(new_string);
        for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
            dest_string[i] = new_string[i];    

    }



    Vehicle get_vehicle(int vehicle_ID)
    {
        switch(vehicle_ID)
        {
            case 1 : //toyota Landcruizer
        {
            Vehicle toyota_landcruizer;
            copyString("SUV",toyota_landcruizer.type); //set type
            copyString("TOYOTA",toyota_landcruizer.make);
            copyString("LAND-CRUIZER",toyota_landcruizer.model);

            toyota_landcruizer.manufacturing_year = 2019;

            return toyota_landcruizer;

            break;
        }

            case 2 : //Nissan Maxima
        {
            Vehicle nissan_maxima;
            copyString("SEDAN",nissan_maxima.type); //set type
            copyString("NISSAN",nissan_maxima.make);
            copyString("MAXIMA",nissan_maxima.model);

            nissan_maxima.manufacturing_year = 2009;

            return nissan_maxima;

            break;
        }


             case 3 : //Ford ranger
        {
            Vehicle ford_ranger;
            copyString("SUV",ford_ranger.type); //set type
            copyString("FORD",ford_ranger.make);
            copyString("RANGER",ford_ranger.model);

           ford_ranger.manufacturing_year = 2016;

           return ford_ranger;

            break;
        }
        }


    }
```

How can i optimize the get_vehicle() function and remove duplicate case labels doing the same thing in each case label ?

Comment: It might be better if your title stated what the program did rather than the help you are seeking. Please see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I've made an edit to the title. What do you think about the new title.?

Comment: I think the title belongs in the body of the question and that the title should be what the program is trying to accomplish. You might also want to take the Hello World out of the code. I'm trying to help you improve the question so that people will stop to look and maybe answer.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!  Is the list of vehicles to be generated by the program or is the list known at compile time?

Comment: @Edward the list is known at compile time.

Comment: What are you doing with the `Vehicle` objects that are returned from the function?  Is read-only access sufficient?  A bit more context to the problem is still needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't Re-Invent the Wheel Unless Absolutely Necessary**
The C programming language already contains the function [strcpy(destination, source)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/string.h/strcpy). You have access to this function and many more string functions when you include string.h in your program. There is also the `char* strncpy(char* dst, const char* src, size_t size);` function that limits the number of characters that will be copied. C library functions have been optimized so that they will perform faster then code you write yourself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

Vehicle get_vehicle(int vehicle_ID)
{
    switch (vehicle_ID)
    {
    case 1: //toyota Landcruizer
    {
        Vehicle toyota_landcruizer;
        strcpy(toyota_landcruizer.type, "SUV"); //set type
        strcpy(toyota_landcruizer.make, "TOYOTA");
        strncpy(toyota_landcruizer.model, "LAND-CRUIZER", 10);
        toyota_landcruizer.manufacturing_year = 2019;
        return toyota_landcruizer;

        break;
    }

    ...
}
```

**Don't Repeat Yourself**
There is a programming principle called the [Don't Repeat Yourself Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) sometimes referred to as DRY code. If you find yourself repeating the same code multiple times it is better to encapsulate it in a function.

To simplify the code in `get_vehicle(int vehicle_ID)` you can write a generic function that creates a vehicle

```
Vehicle add_vehicle(char *make, char *model, char* auto_type, int year)
{
    ...
}

Vehicle get_vehicle(int vehicle_ID)
{
    switch (vehicle_ID)
    {
    case 1: //toyota Landcruizer
        return add_vehicle("TOYOTA", "LAND-CRUISER", "SUV", 2019);

    case 2: //Nissan Maxima
        return= add_vehicle("NISSAN", "MAXIMA", "SEDAN", 2009);

    case 3: //Ford ranger
        return add_vehicle("FORD", "RANGER", "SUV", 2016);
    }
}
```

The `return` statement is enough, no `break` statement is necessary because it can't be reached.

Comment: Many compilers will complain that `get_vehicle()` may fall off the end without returning a value (since they cannot prove that it will be passed a `vehicle_ID` that corresponds to a `case` of the `switch`).  We need a `return` after the `switch`, or a `default:` label.

Comment: @TobySpeight Definitely need a default case, sorry I should have mentioned that along with the magic numbers.

Comment: BTW, if you have an enum for the vehicle IDs, it's better to have the fallback outside the `switch`, as decent compilers will warn about missing `case` labels if you don't account for them with `default`.  That's probably what's wanted in this code.